# Unable to select "select query" in Report Designer in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I used ktr transformation as a data source to a report. When I tried to select query in the prpt, I couldn't do that.normally when we select the "Select query" all columns will be display from the ktr. but it will not display.
I have attached the image to understand the Question  [image]

Comment: Can you see any data when you select `Edit Query` and then click on `Preview` button? Are you sure that ktr has default values for all parameters? Do you get any errors when you try to run this report?

Comment: @user4637357 when i select the Edit query i can preview the data. parameter are ok . when i run only there are no date in reports. because there are no ktr loading